# Socket IO listening all Sessions ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have an application with Socket IO and Session by Redux and persistor.
The problem is that the Socket for each session is listening to all sessions open in my application at that time.

Example:
I'm on client1 and logged in to enter the application. I'm receiving 100 requests per minute (according to my Socket settings).
If a client2 enters the application too, me (client1) and he (client2) will start receiving 200 requests per minute.
If client3 enters, the 3 of us will receive 300 requests per minute, and so on.

That is, the client1 session socket is listening to all open sessions in the application and should only listen to requests from client1 that is logged in its specific session.

**SERVER:**

```
const ioServer = require('http').createServer(server)

class IoConta {
  constructor () {
    let getNotifications

    io.on('connection', socket => {

      if (getNotifications) clearInterval(getNotifications)

    socket.on('getNotifications', async data => {
          getNotifications = setInterval(
          () => this.getNotifications(data.id),
          2000
        )
      })

    io.on('disconnect', () => {
      clearInterval(getNotifications)
    })

    ioServer.listen(3901)
 }

async getNotifications (id) {
    const novas = await Notificacoes.find({
      conta: id,
      read: false
    })

    io.emit('notifications', { notifications: novas, conta: id })
  }
```

**FRONT:**

```
const urlIO = 'http://localhost:3901'

const signOut = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const socket = io(urlIO)
        socket.emit('getNotifications', { id: profile.id })
        socket.on('notifications', data => {
            if (profile.id === data.conta) { 
            dispatch(someDispatch(data)) }
            })
}, [])
```

I need Socket to listen only to requests from the client logged in to the specific session, that is, each client has its own connection to the socket linked to its id.
Am I doing something wrong, for example, by calling `.on` inside the "connect" of the socket, or something?
I appreciate the help